# Is it "incorrect behaviour" for ++ and += operators not to modify the original object?

Tags: c++

Had an exam today and they asked me out of 4 operators, which one required references for "correct behaviour".

```
Foo operator+(Foo lhs, Foo rhs);
Foo operator++(Foo rhs);
Foo operator+=(Foo lhs, Foo rhs);
bool operator<(Foo lhs, Foo rhs);
```

The correct answer according to the solution:

```
Foo operator++(Foo &rhs);
Foo operator+=(Foo &lhs,Foo rhs);
```

Now I question; is it mandated by the standard that "correct behaviour" involves using the operators in the solution in that specific way (references), or can one omit the reference if *you - the programmer - want* the original object to not be affected?

Comment: This exam question is terrible. There is no such thing as "correct behaviour" if you don't define what "correct behaviour" should be...

Comment: I'd say the the wording is slightly off, but it's not a terrible question. Maybe "_expected behaviour_"? And maybe have an actual class such as a rational number class to make it clear that it's not some weird special case (I can't think of any). I also find it weird that these operators aren't member functions, but I guess they did what they had to to illustrate their point.

Comment: As much as I agree with most answers here that there is no such thing as standard or implicit "correct behavior" for those operators, I also get the strong feeling that I know what test-writer had on mind and what correct answer should be. Althogh nobody requires specific functionality from those operators, there usually some ways in which they are expected to work, and a good programer should know that. What wording would you use to ask that question correctly then?

Comment: And BTW: If Foo owns lost of memory (list, array), then the best thing to do would be to use references in all those operators - just marking them const as necesary, right?

Comment: I agree with @j_kubik that there's no universal standard for 'correct behavior' of these operators, but also that making them do anything other than increment / add to the original object violates the [Principle of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_surprise) and is in general a terrible idea. I don't think that (without explicitly defining 'correct' in this context) it's a great exam question, but I do think it should be pretty obvious what the expected answer is.

Comment: Having non-member `operator++` and `operator+=` is a bit weird

Answer (score 2):

The point seems to be that references are required if you want to modify function arguments from the caller's perspective.  Since `+=` and `++` are usually expected to modify their operand, those ones should have references or else they are unlikely to do what people expect.  `<` and `+` however do not modify any of their operands, so passing by value to them could give reasonable semantics.

Comment: I wholly agree, however; is that "correct behaviour"?

Comment: Yes?  No?  Maybe?  I mean, you need to implement a program to have "correct behavior" give any meaning.  A function signature is neither correct nor incorrect by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The "natural" meaning of operators is derived from natural numbers.

For the operators in your question this would mean the following:

- `operator+`: `x = a + b;` should not change a or b. So no reference.
- `operator++`: `a++;` should increment a by 1, so a is changed and we need a reference.
- `operator+=`: `a += b;` should add b to a, so a is changed (hence a reference), and b is not.
- `operator<` : `bool test = a < b;` compares a and b and does not change neither of them.

---

This is the generally expected behaviour. It is by no means mandatory that operators behave like that, but it will save a lot of confusion to keep the basic semantics similar to this one.

---

In the question given to you, the wording "correct behavior" would be poorly chosen. Was it defined in the question or clear from implicit knowledge what "correct" should be? Otherwise the next best answer could be to use the behavior expected for integers as explained above.

Comment: An exact copy of the English question:
"h) Write new declarations for those operators below where one or both of the parameters HAVE to be call-by-reference. Keep call-by-value parameters that will work. We will only look at parameters in the answer and have no interest in return types."

In my own language (Norwegian), it was "...MÅ bruke call-by-referece for å få Korrekt Oppførsel...", which literally translates "HAVE to use call-by-reference to achieve Correct behaviour".

Comment: @BourgondAries: Was there a special sematic for `Foo`?

Comment: none whatsoever, the task was part of a multiple-question exercise and Foo was completely undefined.

Comment: Then "correct" behavior is not sufficiently defined, and it is by no way mandatory by the standard to use a reference. They should have called it at least `LargeInteger` or something.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a usage of user-defined operators that does not respect the standard semantics would be [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/proto.html), a library for building EDSLs using expression templates, for example used by Boost.Lambda, Boost.Phoenix, Boost.Spirit etc.

In this case, a distinct return type is used (i.e. not `Foo`) to allow building a data structure that reflects the structure of an expression, which is then evaluated at a later time.

However, for any concrete type where `++`, `+=` etc. have the usual meaning, it would be necessary to take the first argument by reference to preserve the usual semantics.